# Hibernate lazy loading in detached objects

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I have created a class in which I have set some of it's fields (other entities) to be LAZY loaded. Now I need to use this object after it has been detached from the session, so I obviously need to make sure all the fields that I need are populated before detaching it. I tried just calling the getters to these lazy fields but that didn't seem to work. Anyone have an idea how to force these fields to be loaded?

Comment: are you sure your session is open while calling getters  ?

Comment: Session if definitely open when I call the getters

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Hibernate.initialize(yourObject)
```

will force-initialize the object/collection that is passed to it. You need an active session for this.

If the entity is detached, you'd have to re-attach the object (using `merge(..)`) to an active session and then initialize it.

Comment: `merge` is just for some very special cases. As a rule of a thumb I'd recomment `update`

Comment: @pakore - well, the difference I think is that `merge(..)` can insert a new record as well. But I'm more used to the JPA semantics, so it might be a bit different here.

Comment: Hibernate.initialize is not transitive I believe. So if your object has a lazy collection or lazy field, you need to do Hibernate.initialize(object.getLazyField()) or .initialize(object.getLazyCollection())

Answer (score 3):

You can reattach it to the session. This is the normal way.

```
session.update(yourObject); //This reattachs the object to the current session.
yourObject.someGetter(); //This will work now.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
```

you can add this line into your configuration file,it can fetch your lazy objects even it is detached,but it should be use post 4.1.7 version as there are some connection leakage issue with previous version.see  [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7524)

Answer (score 1):

I know that you asked for Hibernate but [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) has this feature so it might be worth checking out if you are using JPA and not tied to a given implementation. You might run into other problems migrating to EclipseLink though..